# c# serialize object without root element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am working with a 3rd party who has an xml structure for multiple different requests.

Each request has a common header structure and then some specific footer data.

Unfortunately, the header and footer sections are not wrapped within their own element tags and this is something that I can't change.

Some sample contrived requests are shown below:

Sample Request 1

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>
    <RequestType>1</RequestType>
    <User>User01</User>
    <id>1234</id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
</Request>
```

Sample Request 2

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>
    <RequestType>2</RequestType>
    <User>User02</User>
    <id>1235</id>
    <School>The School</School>
    <Teacher>Mrs Smith</Teacher>
</Request>
```

Sample Request 3

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF - 8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>
    <RequestType>3</RequestType>
    <User>User01</User>
    <id>223</id>
    <Work>The Office</Word>
    <Boss>Mr White</Boss>
    <Phone>1234567</Phone>
    <Payday>Friday</Payday>
</Request>
```

You can see that each request has a **RequestType**, **User** and **id**.

My question relates to writing C# code that will encapsulate this Xml for serialization.

To me, it seems *wrong* to have each of my C# classes having the repeated header (**RequestType**, **User** and **id**) data.

I have tried using generics (see sample code below) but that leads to my question.

**Question**: How can I serialize my generic object `Footer` so that it is not wrapped within "root" *Footer* element?

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Request")]
public class GenericRequest<typeT>
{
    public GenericRequest()
    {
    }

    public int RequestType { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public typeT Footer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid xml. If you know the delimiter you can do a split and parse one by one.

Comment: I have edited the question to make the samples clearer - apologies for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with interface IFooter, which can have different implementor as per requirement (e.g.

```
interface IFooter : ISerializable 
{
 //Define common member.
}

public class Footer1: IFooter
{
 // define members (e.g. work) 
}

public class Footer2: IFooter
{
 // define members 
}

public class Footer3: IFooter
{
 // define members 
}
```

Now serialize main class

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Request")]
public class GenericRequest
{
  public GenericRequest()
  {
  }


  public int RequestType { get; set; }

  public string User { get; set; }

  public int id { get; set; }

  public IFooter Footer { get; set; }
}
```

Visit [How can I serialize an object that has an interface as a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821780/how-can-i-serialize-an-object-that-has-an-interface-as-a-property) for reference.